# can't get input type number value

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="spacing">
   <h5>Bill</h5>
   <label for="bill"></label>
   <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" value="">
</div>
```

```
<script>
const bill = document.querySelector("#bill");

bill.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
console.log(bill.value);
})
</script>
```

i keep getting this error --
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Comment: is your script below or above the input element in the file? I'm guessing above - therefore the element doesn't yet exist, therefore the fail

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are reading control before document is ready.

**Solution 1**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>       
$(document).ready(function () {
   const bill = document.getElementById("bill");
   bill.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
   console.log(bill.value);
  })
});
</script>
```

**Solution 2** Without JQuery

```
<script>
    function printVal() {
       const bill = document.getElementById("bill");
       if (bill != null) {
          bill.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
          console.log(bill.value);
        });
      }
    }           
</script>

<div class="spacing">
  <h5>Bill</h5>
  <label for="bill"></label>
  <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" onkeypress="printVal();">
</div>
```

Comment: reason for downvote and it is too fast.

Comment: it can be other solution but my solution is also working. you can also suggest your solution. OP will opt better answer.

Comment: Yes, but 1) the question hasn't tagged jQuery, and 2) you don't use any jQuery for any other part of your answer. Why introduce a big JS resource when you can use vanilla JS to check if the document is ready?

Comment: I was modifying but some one down voted immediately.

Comment: JQuery is slower than Vannila Javascript

Comment: @RinshanKolayil Please share your answer too. The OP will opt better one.

Comment: I am getting output with same code he given. I think it is some debugging issue. May be Mr.Bravo comment to the answer might be the reason

Comment: My point was @AmitVerma if you're going to introduce jQuery [use it for all the code](https://jsfiddle.net/q6o2cw7j/).

Comment: Yeah my badd! Script wasn't below the code.

Comment: Btw thanks for different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Either move your script to just before the `</body>` tag so you ensure that the DOM has loaded successfully before you try and access it, or use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event to check to see if the DOM has loaded before performing any operations on it.

You should also reference the value of the target of the event you pass into the listener rather than `bill`.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const bill = document.querySelector("#bill");
  bill.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="spacing">
  <h5>Bill</h5>
  <label for="bill"></label>
  <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: How about closing this as a dupe instead of adding yet another answer that's already available in [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) ?

Comment: _"You should also reference the value of the target of the event you pass into the listener rather than `bill`"_ - Why? `bill.value` would absolutely work. And why `e.target.value` and not `this.value`?

Answer (score 0):

The script tag should be *after* the html you want to apply the handler to, preferrably right before the closing `body` tag.

Another way to make this work is to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). The input handler is attached to the document. Detection of the input element is done within the handler function. In that case the script placement doesn't matter.

Example

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener(`input`, evt => {
    if (evt.target.id === `bill` && evt.target.value.trim().length) {
      console.log(evt.target.value);}
    });
</script>

<div class="spacing">
  <h5>Bill</h5>
  <label for="bill"></label>
  <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: How about closing this as a dupe instead of adding yet another answer that's already available in [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert it into integer

```
<script>
  const bill = document.querySelector("#bill");
  bill.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    var a = parseInt(bill.value);
    console.log(bill.value);
    console.log(typeof a);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be some debugging issue as mentioned by Mr. Bravo in the comment. I am getting the output with same code you given.

```js
const bill = document.querySelector("#bill");
bill.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    console.log(this.value); // You can use `this` keyword
});
```

```html
<div class="spacing">
  <h5>Bill</h5>
  <label for="bill"></label>
  <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" value="">
</div>
```

But following code gives me error as you got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

```
<script>
    const bill = document.querySelector("#bill");
    bill.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
</script>
<div class="spacing">
    <h5>Bill</h5>
    <label for="bill"></label>
    <input id="bill" type="number" name="bill" value="">
</div>
```